How to correctly calculate the intersection number of the exceptional line with the canonical divisor of the blowup?
Let $X$ be a projective subvariety in $\Bbb P^{3}$ which is given by the equation $xyw-z^{3}=0$. Let $\widetilde{X} \rightarrow X$ be the blow up at the point $q :[x:y:z:w]=[0:0:0:1]$. There are two exceptional lines $C_{1}$, $C_{2}$ , and they  intersect at a point. I am tring to compute $K_{\widetilde{X}} \cdot C_{1}$.
Denote $f: W=Bl_{q}(\Bbb P^{3}) \rightarrow \Bbb P^{3}$, and $E=\Bbb P^{2}$ is the exceptional divisor. By using the following formulas  $$K_{W}=f^{*}K_{\Bbb P^{3}} + E,$$ $$K_{\widetilde{X}} =
(K_{W} + \widetilde{X})|_\widetilde{X},$$ we have:
$$K_{\widetilde{X}} \cdot C_{1} =(f^{*}K_{\Bbb P^{3}} + E+\widetilde{X})|_\widetilde{X} \cdot C_{1},$$ and $$f^{*}K_{\Bbb P^{3}} \cdot C_{1}=0,$$ since $C_{1}$ is contracted by $f$. Then, note that $C_{1} \subset E \cap \widetilde{X}$, we obtain:
$$(E+\widetilde{X})|_\widetilde{X} \cdot C_{1}=(E+\widetilde{X})|_{E} \cdot C_{1}$$ by using projection formula.
Moreover, $E|_{E}=\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^{2}}(-1)$ , $\widetilde{X}|_{E}=\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^{2}}(2)$.
So, the answer seems to be $1$. However, someone told me that $\widetilde{X} \rightarrow X$ is a crepant resolution, so the answer should be $0$.
Could you tell me where the mistake is?

well, there is 2E here.......
